# Disable auto translation for input values in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

Symfony2 automatically translate the input field values with type decimal or integer.
I have a two languages for my app: arabic and english
I created an Entity with the following field:

```
/**
 * @var float $price
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=true)
 * 
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.\d{1,2})?$/",message="Incorrect price.")
 * @Assert\Type(type="float")
 * @Assert\Min(0)
 */
private $price;
```

In form I let the sf to guess a field type:

```
$builder->add('price')
```

I load the form for editing this entity in Arabic Interface.
In the price field I see `١٢٫٤` instead of `12.40`. 
I can't save the form because HTML5 validation is failed. 
If I enter 12.40 in the current field and save Entity, 12 will be saved, instead of 12.40.

Why? How to disable it? how to validate the Arabic digits?
Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** solved, see below

Comment: Just an idea, not sure if it's enough : you can try to force using the "number" type for your form widget : $builder->add('price', 'number')

Comment: yes, I tried it. If I set a `number` type or `integer` for widget then symfony translate the value. If I set a `text` widget then symfony doesn't translate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer why it happens [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/IntegerType.php)
As you can see, symfony register a ViewTransformer for these widget types:

```
    $builder->addViewTransformer(
        new IntegerToLocalizedStringTransformer(
            $options['precision'],
            $options['grouping'],
            $options['rounding_mode']
    ));
```

Current transformer transform an integer value to localized string. It happens for the `number` widget (NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer) and `money` widget (MoneyToLocalizedStringTransformer) too.

So I think need to register a new FieldType which will not used a ViewTransformer.

**EDIT:** I solved the problem just disabling intl extension and now all numeric fields are using a default english numbers. If you enable the intl extension you should use only localized numbers in the input values, it's a default behavior.

Comment: i think my answer above deserves to be the correct answer as it gets rid of the issue without disabling intl extension and loosing its advantages.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but i hope my answer will help anyone encounters this issue.
Instead of disabling intl extension as suggested above, you can use Data Transformers in form type to manually set the default locale to English and that will let the fields to be shown with English digits.

1) Use [Data Transformers](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/data_transformers.html) to interrupt (hook into) the process of showing the field data.

2) [Manually set Locale to English](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/intl.html#locales).

here is what i've done with dateOfBirth field in the form type:

```js
$builder -> add(
  $builder -> create(
    'dateOfBirth', DateType::class, array(
      'label' => 'Date of Birth',
      'widget' => 'single_text',
      'required' => false,
      'html5' => false,
      'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']
    )) -> addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
    function($dateOfBirth) {
      \Locale::setDefault('en');
      return $dateOfBirth;
    },
    function($dateOfBirth) {
      return $dateOfBirth;
    }
  ))
);
```